# React Native Expo app crashing on android apk file when ask location permission

Tags: react-native, android-permissions, expo

I have problem with expo standalone app. the problem is with the ask permissions for locations. in the development mode, app asks for location permissions and works well. there is no bugs. after build the app using expo build:android, it creates a android standalone app. and after installing that APK and try to access the same page that asks for location permissions, the app is crashed and restarted.

```
  Expo CLI 4.7.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19042
    Binaries:
      Node: 14.15.4 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      Yarn: 1.22.10 - C:\Users\ISLAMSOFT\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn.CMD
      npm: 7.6.3 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: Version  4.2.0.0 AI-202.7660.26.42.7486908
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~40.0.0 => 40.0.1
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz => 0.63.2
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

in app.json I added this but not solve the problem

```
"android": {
      "permissions":[
        "ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION",
        "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION",
        "CAMERA",
        "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
        "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
      ]
    },
```

I don't know how to test the apk file to check the error

Answer (score 0):

## Possible reason 1

---

I had same problem in my expo app few days earlier. There I needed **AUDIO_RECORDING** permission for my app. The app was fine in development but crashing on the production.

I have found the I missed the `await`  keyword befor taking the permission in `useEffect`. Something like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING)
 }, [])
```

Then I completely removed the above code. Then the permission was taken from an `onPressIn` event of a `TouchableOpacity` button. The code was something like this:

```
  const startRecording = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING);
    if (status !== 'granted') return;
    
    // Other codes...
  }
```

You should double check how you took your permission.

## Possible reason 2

---

Sometimes the expo app crashed because of wrong css value like this:

```
{flex: '1'}
```

Instead of

```
{flex: 1}
```

This kind of small mistakes crashed my apps many times. You should check all of your css property values.

Comment: thanx for your comment 
how can I check the errors of apk file, I can't find any error in development mode and try to run application in production mode but not errors also, only in apk file

Comment: actually you can't test the apk. Try to keep chaning the codes where  you have doubt and keep building apk.  Or your can run this command `expo start --no-dev --minify` to see if any errors comes up.

Comment: I tried this "expo start --no-dev --minify" no errors   it just crashed when press on button of this function  let { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);

Comment: Does this crashed on development now? Or on the apk?

Comment: only on apk file

Comment: If your code has a public repository then share the link, can't tell anything else without seeing the entire code.

Comment: https://github.com/FatmaMahmoud698/Test-Location/blob/main/HeaderLocation.js    this is the component hang the app